# Center of gravity $\frac{1}{\lambda_d(E)}\int_E xdx \space$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

We are looking at $\mathbb{R}^d$ with the Lebesgue measure. Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be bounded and measurable with $\lambda_d(E) > 0$. The center of gravity is component-wise defined as $$\frac{1}{\lambda_d(E)}\int_E xdx \space.$$

How do I calculate the center of gravity of the cube $[0,T]$, $T>0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cube $[0,T]^{3}\subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ has centre of mass at some point $y=(y_{1},y_{2},y_{3})$. We can compute $y_{i}$ by the integral

$$ y_{i} = \frac{\displaystyle\int_{[0,T]^{3}}p_{i}(x) dx}{\displaystyle\int_{[0,T]^{3}}dx} = \frac{\displaystyle\int_{[0,T]^{3}}p_{i}(x) dx}{\lambda_{3}([0,T]^{3})}$$

where $p_{i}$ is the projection of $x$ into the $i$th (canonical) basis vector of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ i.e. for $x=(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$, $p_{i}(x)=x_{i}$.

I assume you are familiar with triple integrals and thus this simply becomes an exercise in computing them.